# SQL and empty rows in the beginning of the data

Tags: sql-server

Earlier I have always been able to import to SQL Server data having column names on first row and information beginning from second row. However, now I should work with data having different structure and I have not possibilities to fix it, so I have to take it as "given".

In data there is first three totally empty rows. Column names are located on fourth and fifth rows, so that names of first three columns are on fourth row and names of other columns on fifth one. Information itself begins from sixth row.

I have no idea, how to manage with this kind of data structure in SQL environment? Former practices seems to be useless, or at least results have been far away from that what I want and need.

Comment: I would just write a PowerShell script, ignoring the first 5 records and import the delimited data from the 6th record on.If you want to use SSIS or other ETL tool, add the appropriate tag to your question.